# htaccess not showing mysql

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite urls but its not going how I planned.

I want from this:

`/category.php?nameid=Test&id=1`

to this:

`/c/Test/1`

Currently is only this one working:
`/c/Test/` When I go to `/c/Test/1/` I see a white page, he doesn't take information from the mysql

My htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule c/(.*)$ category.php?nameID=$1 [L]
RewriteRule c/(.*)/(.*)$ category.php?nameID=$1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)[\s%20]+(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=NOSPACE:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:NOSPACE} =1
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

my php code of that page:

```
 <?php
                // BEGIN OF SHOWING CONTENT PAGE
                if (isset($_GET['id'])){
                $naamID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['nameID']);
                $id     = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
                $idnext = $id + 1;
                $gn     = (" SELECT * FROM category WHERE name='".$naamID."'") or die(mysql_error());
                $go     = (" SELECT * FROM post WHERE id='".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
                $gnn    = mysql_query($gn) or die(mysql_error());
                $goo    = mysql_query($go) or die(mysql_error());
                $gnnn   = mysql_fetch_array($gnn);
                $gooo   = mysql_fetch_array($goo);
                ?>


                <?php
                echo '<p>';
                if(empty($gooo['youtube'])){
                } else {
                ?>              <h1> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($gooo["title"]); ?> </h1><br />
                <?php
                $fullurl1 = $gooo['youtube'];
                $videoid1=substr($fullurl1,-11);
                ?>
                <?php
                echo '<p><a href="/editpost.php?id='.$gooo['id'].'"><i>Edit this post</i></a><br />';
                echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'.$videoid1.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br />';
                echo '</p>';

                }

                if(empty($gooo['pic'])){
                } else {
                ?> <h1> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($gooo["title"]); ?> </h1><br />
                <?php
                echo '<p><a href="/editpost.php?id='.$gooo['id'].'"><i>Edit this post</i></a><br />';
                echo '<img src="'.$gooo["pic"].'" style="max-height: auto; max-width: 600px;"/><br></p>';
                }
                echo '</p>'; 
                }
                ?>



                <?php
                // END OF SHOWING CONTENT PAGE

                // BEGIN category page
                if(isset($_GET['nameID'])){

                // PAGE BEGIN
                $count_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY date ASC");
                $nr = mysql_num_rows($count_query);
                if(isset($_GET['page'])){
                $page = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_GET['page']);
                }else{
                $page = 1;
                }
                $perPage = 5;
                $lastPage = ceil($nr / $perPage);

                if($page < 1) {
                $page = 1;
                } else if ($page > $lastPage){
                $page = $lastPage;
                }
                $limit = 'LIMIT ' . ($page - 1) * $perPage .',' .$perPage;
                $query = ("SELECT * FROM post WHERE cat='".$nameID."' ORDER BY date DESC ".$limit."");

                if($lastPage != 1){


                if($page != $lastPage){
                $naamID2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['nameID']);
                $next = $page + 1;
                $pagination .= '<a href="/category.php?nameID='.$naamID2.'&page='.$next.'">Next..   </a>';
                }

                if($page != 1){
                $naamID1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['nameID']);
                $prev = $page - 1;
                $pagination .= '<a href="/category.php?nameID='.$naamID1.'&page='.$prev.'">   ..Prev</a>';


                }
                }
                // PAGE END 
                ?>

                <?php

                $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['nameID']);

                $nameID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['nameID']);
                $na = (" SELECT * FROM category WHERE name='".$nameID."'") or die(mysql_error());
                $nb = (" SELECT * FROM post WHERE cat='".$nameID."' ORDER BY date DESC ".$limit."") or die(mysql_error());
                $naa = mysql_query($na) or die(mysql_error());
                $nbb = mysql_query($nb) or die(mysql_error());
                $naaa = mysql_fetch_array($naa);
                ?>

                <h1> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($naaa["name"]); ?></h1><br />
                <i> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($naaa["description"]); ?> </i><br />
                <?php
                echo '<p><a href="category.php"><i>back to all categoties</i></a></p>';

                while($nbbb=mysql_fetch_array($nbb, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

                $fullurl = $nbbb['youtube'];
                $videoid=substr($fullurl,-11);

                // showing youtube video when there is no picture
                if(empty($nbbb['youtube'])){
                } else {
                if( $nbbb['NSFW'] == 0) {
                echo '<h1><a href="category.php?nameid='.$naaa['name'].'&id='.$nbbb['title'].'">';?><?php echo htmlspecialchars($nbbb["title"]); ?></a></h1><br><?php
                echo '<p><iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'.$videoid.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
                echo '</p>';
                } 

                if( $nbbb['NSFW'] == 1) {
                echo '<h1><a href="category.php?nameid='.$naaa['name'].'&id='.$nbbb['title'].'">';?><?php echo htmlspecialchars($nbbb["title"]); ?></a></h1><br><?php
                echo '<p><a href="category.php?nameid='.$naaa['name'].'&id='.$nbbb['title'].'"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/w88amwc.png"/></a><br>';
                echo '</p>';
                } 

                }
                // showing picture when there is no youtube
                if(empty($nbbb['pic'])){
                } else {

                if( $nbbb['NSFW'] == 0) {
                echo '<h1><a href="category.php?nameid='.$naaa['name'].'&id='.$nbbb['title'].'">'; ?><?php echo htmlspecialchars($nbbb["title"]); ?> <?php echo '</a></h1><br>'; ?>
                <?php
                echo '<p><img src="'.$nbbb["pic"].'" style="max-height: auto; max-width: 600px;"/>';
                echo '</p>';
                } 

                if( $nbbb['NSFW'] == 1) {
                echo '<h1><a href="category.php?nameid='.$naaa['name'].'&id='.$nbbb['title'].'">'; ?><?php echo htmlspecialchars($nbbb["title"]); ?><?php echo '</a></h1><br>'; ?>
                <?php
                echo '<p><a href="category.php?nameid='.$naaa['name'].'&id='.$nbbb['title'].'"/><img src="http://i.imgur.com/w88amwc.png"/></a><br>';
                echo '</p>';
                } 


                }
                }
                echo '<p>';
                echo '<b><i>'.$pagination.'</b></i>';
                echo '</p>';

                }// END OF SHOWING MAIN PAGE OF CATEGORYS
                ?>
```

Comment: You should have this logic in PHP, not in .htaccess really..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule c/(.*)$ category.php?nameID=$1 [L]
RewriteRule c/(.*)/(.*)$ category.php?nameID=$1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

First line says that EVERYTHING (times 0 or more) will get to the variable $1. So when you enter `/c/Test/1/` you will go to the `category.php?nameID=Test/1/`. You need to rewrite it a bit, to allow only characters you want e.g. only a-zA-z construction. Then the same with line number two, in the first variable place e.g. a-zA-Z and in the second variable place 0-9 since it's ID so probably it is an int. Example script?

```
RewriteRule c/([a-zA-Z]+)$ category.php?nameID=$1 [L]
RewriteRule c/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)$ category.php?nameID=$1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out with this. But have now a little problem on the page `category.php?nameID=$1&id=$2` he displays what I need but including details from ?nameid=$1 which I don't want to display

Comment: Oh wait, where do you get that details from nameid?

Comment: What is your query to the database?

Comment: I don't know which you mean so I've uploaded my script to pastebin. http://pastebin.com/TrKftbg6

Comment: This paste does not exist, probably you gave 10 min in the options. Paste it in the main post.

Comment: just added it now was away from the computer.